# Exam document class

Tags: exam

At the moment my document displays the marks for a bonus questions as, e.g. (3 (bonus)). I don't want the bonus to be there; I just want (3).

I'm using the command `\bonuspointpoints{mark}{marks}` but it seems to be being ignored and the marks still appear with (bonus) in brackets.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{exam}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\marksnotpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\addpoints
\totalformat{{\bf (\totalpoints \, marks)}}
\bonustotalformat{{\bf (\totalbonuspoints \, marks)}}
\bonuspointpoints{mark}{marks}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\bonusquestion[3] What is my name?
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Providing a minimum working example (MWE) will enable us answer your question better. See [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) how to provide an MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have to tweak at two places,

1. `\bonuspointname{\relax}` will reset the word bonus. Try playing putting other words in place of `\relax`.
2. `\bonuspointformat` controls the actual format how the actual points are displayed. You can get your intended format using `\bonuspointformat{[\thepoints]}`.

So, your minimal example becomes,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{exam}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\marksnotpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\addpoints
\totalformat{{\bf (\totalpoints \, marks)}}
\bonustotalformat{{\bf (\totalbonuspoints \, marks)}}

\begin{document}

\bonuspointname{\relax}
\bonuspointformat{[\thepoints]}


\begin{questions}
\bonusquestion[3] What is your name?
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I did not know about this package before, so answering your question was an introduction to a very useful package.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `\bonuspointpoints` macro only seems to affect marks that are not placed in the right margin. To achieve the effect that you want, use `\marginbonuspointname`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\pointsinrightmargin
\marginbonuspointname{}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\bonusquestion[3] What is my name?
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

That said, I don't think using bonus points that are not clearly marked as such is a good idea.